Why are the results of BTC message signature implemented in Python different from those on electrum?
from bit import Key
from bit.format import verify_sig
import base64
from hashlib import sha256

# Use WIF format private key
wif_private_key = 'Kxb19KFrrqrmT79bvG4tnKibVcgppavcvjkP1iBGGjnH787H39QG'
key = Key(wif_private_key)

# Message to be signed
message = '''ok 666'''
message_bytes = message.encode('utf-8')

# Compute SHA-256 hash of the message
message_hash = sha256(message_bytes).digest()

# Sign the hash of the message
signature_bytes = key.sign(message_hash)

# Convert the signature to Base64 encoding
signature_base64 = base64.b64encode(signature_bytes).decode('utf-8')
print(f'Signature (Base64): {signature_base64}')

# Verify the signature
# Decode the actual Base64 encoded signature
signature_bytes = base64.b64decode(signature_base64)
is_valid = verify_sig(signature_bytes, message_hash, key.public_key)
print(f'Is the signature valid? {is_valid}')

python result is
MEUCIQDGOkOlG2DMAcZ4/nvsUNi4ZxbTKGJFIx0h76QkBLVmqgIgd2McFwd+/ZHxCcktZffZS762gA5o8oRM5u4tqORp6HA=
The electrum result is
IDVIF+7m9nKMvxAKo88PNwLJeg8H2MA9WoDZgjDCs0boKyuFdqWnTSCuAobVmzJr+NzqlCg180yvc5vsfsVeBjA=
After multiple verifications, electrum is correct.
